# codeigniter join from 2nd table id with 3rd table id multi rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to join multiple tables, as in my picture:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
$this->db->select('
  pt2.turl as `p_img`,
  p.title as `p_title`,
  p.text as `p_text`,
  p.create as `p_date`,
  pt3.turl as `c_img`,
  u.name as `c_name`,
  c.text as `c_text`,      
  c.create as `c_date`
');

$this->db->from('posts as p, users as u, photos as pt2, photos as pt3');    
$this->db->join('comments as c', 'p.id=c.pid AND u.id=c.uid');
$this->db->join('posts as p2', 'p2.pid=pt2.id', 'rihgt');
$this->db->join('users as u2', 'u2.photoid=pt3.id', 'right');
$this->db->order_by('c.id', 'DESC');
$this->db->limit('7');
$qry = $this->db->get();
return $qry->result();
```

Comment: you have typo later in the in code: right::rihgt also have a look at: blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is kind of what you're looking for. I haven't tried it out so it may not be exact, but you shouldn't need to make 2 table associations (pt2 and pt3) for the same table in the join. Just Include them in the select and join on the unique ID's

The "Left" is a join that is centered around you're left table so everything hangs off of that. Since you are joining the users table before the photo table, you should be able to join on its columns.

Hope this helps. Let me know if I missed something. :)

```
$select = array(
    pt2.turl as `p_img`,
    p.title as `p_title`,
    p.text as `p_text`,
    p.create as `p_date`,
    pt2.turl as `c_img`,
    u.name as `c_name`,
    c.text as `c_text`,      
    c.create as `c_date`
);

//Set tables to variables. Just makes it easier for me
$postsTable = "posts as p"; //This will be your left table. 
$userTable = "Users as u";
$commentsTable = "comments as c";
$photosTable = "photos as pt2";

$this
    ->db
        ->select($select)
        ->from($postsTable)
            ->join($userTable, "p.uid = u.id", "left")
            ->join($commentsTable, "p.cid = c.id", "left")
            ->join($photosTable, "u.photoid = pt2.id", "left")
        ->get();
```

Comment: i need post and user image form photos table

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself
It would be like this:

```
$select= array (
    //'*',
    'pt.turl p_img',
    'p.title p_title',
    'p.text p_text',
    'p.create p_date',
    'pt2.turl c_img',
    'c.text c_text',
    'u.name c_name',
    'c.create c_date'
);

$from = array (
    'posts p'
);

$qry = $this
        ->db
          ->select($select)
          ->from($from)
          ->join('comments c', 'c.pid=p.id')
          ->join('photos pt', 'pt.id=p.pid')
          ->join('users u', 'u.id=c.uid')
          ->join('photos pt2', 'u.photoid=pt2.id')
          ->order_by('c.create', 'DESC')
          ->limit('7')
          ->get();    

return $qry->result();
```